# Declare that a variable must not be captured by a Block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Is there a way to prevent a variable from being captured into a block?

I'm wanting something like this:

```
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    CoreDataObject *coreDataObject = [self getObject];
    NSString *name = coreDataObject.name;
    [self doThingWithCompletion:^{
        // I never want to use coreDataObject here, but I might want to use name.
    }];
}];
```

Yes, it's true that this won't capture `coreDataObject`. But if I accidentally use it in the block, it will. Is there a way to declare that `coreDataObject` should never be captured?

So far, the best I've come up with is this:

```
__block NSString *name;
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    CoreDataObject *coreDataObject = [self getObject];
    name = coreDataObject.name;
}];
[self doThingWithCompletion:^{
    // coreDataObject is no longer in scope here
}];
```

However if `doThingWithCompletion` needs Core Data locking I've just turned one lock into two.

Comment: You could explicitly set `coreDataObject` to nil after you cache `name`.

Comment: Create the block in a special method and pass parameters there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a scope block (not the closure type of block, just the C compound-statement kind of block) to make sure that `coreDataObject` can't be used:

```
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSString *name;

    {
        CoreDataObject *coreDataObject = [self getObject];
        name = coreDataObject.name;
    }

    [self doThingWithCompletion:^{
        // I never want to use coreDataObject here, but I might want to use name.
    }];
}];
```

In simple cases like this, you could also just eliminate the `coreDataObject` variable entirely:

```
    NSString *name = [self getObject].name;
```

Comment: Not sure why i didn't see this. Thanks. :)